Нужна ли запятая после «будет» или достаточно одной?
Моя фантазия на тему того, что будет если дать Вейдеру вменяемую попаданку-жену.

• Нужны две запятые:
Моя фантазия на тему того, что будет, если дать Вейдеру вменяемую попаданку-жену.
Это сложноподчиненное предложение с последовательным подчинением (три основы).

6. Между придаточными частями сложноподчиненного предложения с последовательным подчинением запятая ставится на общих основаниях...

• Примеры
Сейчас проводили сценарии того, что будет, если власть в Пакистане захватят исламистские фундаменталисты или даже террористы (Валерий Лебедев. Предчувствие третьей мировой // «Пятое измерение», 2002).
Джек порой думал, что мама уже устала искать папу или, хуже, стала бояться того, что будет, если они его найдут (Джон Ирвинг. Покуда я тебя не обрету).
Знаки препинания в сложноподчиненном предложении с несколькими придаточными
